# Alexa Skills Kit - Custom Skill that Plays Audio from our iOS app's API

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to write a unique Alexa Skill for the Amazon Alexa. I want to write a custom Lambda Function that plays the audio content contained at the following api (https://api.ense.nyc/latest).

I've read through all of Amazon's documentation on the subject:

- [Building a Custom Skill](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/overviews/steps-to-build-a-custom-skill)
- Flashbriefing Skill

I am confused about exactly how to proceed in writing a unique lambda function.

Comment: Did you read the linked page: [Creating an AWS Lambda Function for a Skill](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/developing-an-alexa-skill-as-a-lambda-function) from `Step 2` of the `Building a Custom Skill` page you mentioned? It, literally, has a step-by-step guide on creating a `Lambda Function`. Also, you should tag your question with the `aws-lambda` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Playing audio in alexa is a bit tricky than regular skills.

Looks like you need to do:

-Parse your JSON and create some kind of object that holds audio url and audio cards.

-Then you need to set skill state to PLAY_MODE start playing audios with ask `audioPlayerPlay()` command. (https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/custom-audioplayer-interface-reference#audioplayer-directives)

-Then you need to set audio event handlers to keep track of the audio events.

-You need to set intents to let user play next or previous audios.

List goes on...

Here is a sample podcast skill that parses an XML feed and plays the audio

https://github.com/bespoken/streamer

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in the Lambda Function for playing the first audio item. Enjoy!

```
/**
 * App ID for the skill
 */
//var APP_ID = undefined; //OPTIONAL: replace with "amzn1.echo-sdk-ams.app.[your-unique-value-here]";

/**
 * The AlexaSkill prototype and helper functions
 */

var APP_ID = undefined;

//var AlexaSkill = require('./AlexaSkill');

//////
/**
    Copyright 2014-2015 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.

    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"). You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. A copy of the License is located at

        http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0/

    or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
*/



//////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////  /AlexaSkill.js File Starts /////
//////////////////////////////////////////////




'use strict';

function AlexaSkill(appId) {
    this._appId = appId;
}

AlexaSkill.speechOutputType = {
    PLAIN_TEXT: 'PlainText',
    SSML: 'SSML'
}

AlexaSkill.prototype.requestHandlers = {
    LaunchRequest: function (event, context, response) {
        this.eventHandlers.onLaunch.call(this, event.request, event.session, response);
    },

    IntentRequest: function (event, context, response) {
        this.eventHandlers.onIntent.call(this, event.request, event.session, response);
    },

    SessionEndedRequest: function (event, context) {
        this.eventHandlers.onSessionEnded(event.request, event.session);
        context.succeed();
    }
};

/**
 * Override any of the eventHandlers as needed
 */
AlexaSkill.prototype.eventHandlers = {
    /**
     * Called when the session starts.
     * Subclasses could have overriden this function to open any necessary resources.
     */
    onSessionStarted: function (sessionStartedRequest, session) {
    },

    /**
     * Called when the user invokes the skill without specifying what they want.
     * The subclass must override this function and provide feedback to the user.
     */
    onLaunch: function (launchRequest, session, response) {
        throw "onLaunch should be overriden by subclass";
    },

    /**
     * Called when the user specifies an intent.
     */
    onIntent: function (intentRequest, session, response) {
        var intent = intentRequest.intent,
            intentName = intentRequest.intent.name,
            intentHandler = this.intentHandlers[intentName];
        if (intentHandler) {
            console.log('dispatch intent = ' + intentName);
            intentHandler.call(this, intent, session, response);
        } else {
            throw 'Unsupported intent = ' + intentName;
        }
    },

    /**
     * Called when the user ends the session.
     * Subclasses could have overriden this function to close any open resources.
     */
    onSessionEnded: function (sessionEndedRequest, session) {
    }
};

/**
 * Subclasses should override the intentHandlers with the functions to handle specific intents.
 */
AlexaSkill.prototype.intentHandlers = {};

AlexaSkill.prototype.execute = function (event, context) {
    try {
        console.log("session applicationId: " + event.session.application.applicationId);

        // Validate that this request originated from authorized source.
        if (this._appId && event.session.application.applicationId !== this._appId) {
            console.log("The applicationIds don't match : " + event.session.application.applicationId + " and "
                + this._appId);
            throw "Invalid applicationId";
        }

        if (!event.session.attributes) {
            event.session.attributes = {};
        }

        if (event.session.new) {
            this.eventHandlers.onSessionStarted(event.request, event.session);
        }

        // Route the request to the proper handler which may have been overriden.
        var requestHandler = this.requestHandlers[event.request.type];
        requestHandler.call(this, event, context, new Response(context, event.session));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Unexpected exception " + e);
        context.fail(e);
    }
};

var Response = function (context, session) {
    this._context = context;
    this._session = session;
};

function createSpeechObject(optionsParam) {
    if (optionsParam && optionsParam.type === 'SSML') {
        return {
            type: optionsParam.type,
            ssml: optionsParam.speech
        };
    } else {
        return {
            type: optionsParam.type || 'PlainText',
            text: optionsParam.speech || optionsParam
        }
    }
}

Response.prototype = (function () {
    var buildSpeechletResponse = function (options) {
        var alexaResponse = {
            outputSpeech: createSpeechObject(options.output),
            shouldEndSession: options.shouldEndSession
        };
        if (options.reprompt) {
            alexaResponse.reprompt = {
                outputSpeech: createSpeechObject(options.reprompt)
            };
        }
        if (options.cardTitle && options.cardContent) {
            alexaResponse.card = {
                type: "Simple",
                title: options.cardTitle,
                content: options.cardContent
            };
        }
        var returnResult = {
                version: '1.0',
                response: alexaResponse
        };
        if (options.session && options.session.attributes) {
            returnResult.sessionAttributes = options.session.attributes;
        }
        return returnResult;
    };

    return {
        tell: function (speechOutput) {
            this._context.succeed(buildSpeechletResponse({
                session: this._session,
                output: speechOutput,
                shouldEndSession: true
            }));
        },
        tellWithCard: function (speechOutput, cardTitle, cardContent) {
            this._context.succeed(buildSpeechletResponse({
                session: this._session,
                output: speechOutput,
                cardTitle: cardTitle,
                cardContent: cardContent,
                shouldEndSession: true
            }));
        },
        ask: function (speechOutput, repromptSpeech) {
            this._context.succeed(buildSpeechletResponse({
                session: this._session,
                output: speechOutput,
                reprompt: repromptSpeech,
                shouldEndSession: false
            }));
        },
        askWithCard: function (speechOutput, repromptSpeech, cardTitle, cardContent) {
            this._context.succeed(buildSpeechletResponse({
                session: this._session,
                output: speechOutput,
                reprompt: repromptSpeech,
                cardTitle: cardTitle,
                cardContent: cardContent,
                shouldEndSession: false
            }));
        }
    };
})();




//////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////  AlexaSkill.js File Ends  //////
//////////////////////////////////////////////










'use strict';

function AlexaSkill(appId) {
    this._appId = appId;
}

AlexaSkill.speechOutputType = {
    PLAIN_TEXT: 'PlainText',
    SSML: 'SSML'
}

AlexaSkill.prototype.requestHandlers = {
    LaunchRequest: function (event, context, response) {
        this.eventHandlers.onLaunch.call(this, event.request, event.session, response);
    },

    IntentRequest: function (event, context, response) {
        this.eventHandlers.onIntent.call(this, event.request, event.session, response);
    },

    SessionEndedRequest: function (event, context) {
        this.eventHandlers.onSessionEnded(event.request, event.session);
        context.succeed();
    }
};

/**
 * Override any of the eventHandlers as needed
 */
AlexaSkill.prototype.eventHandlers = {
    /**
     * Called when the session starts.
     * Subclasses could have overriden this function to open any necessary resources.
     */
    onSessionStarted: function (sessionStartedRequest, session) {
    },

    /**
     * Called when the user invokes the skill without specifying what they want.
     * The subclass must override this function and provide feedback to the user.
     */
    onLaunch: function (launchRequest, session, response) {
        throw "onLaunch should be overriden by subclass";
    },

    /**
     * Called when the user specifies an intent.
     */
    onIntent: function (intentRequest, session, response) {
        var intent = intentRequest.intent,
            intentName = intentRequest.intent.name,
            intentHandler = this.intentHandlers[intentName];
        if (intentHandler) {
            console.log('dispatch intent = ' + intentName);
            intentHandler.call(this, intent, session, response);
        } else {
            throw 'Unsupported intent = ' + intentName;
        }
    },

    /**
     * Called when the user ends the session.
     * Subclasses could have overriden this function to close any open resources.
     */
    onSessionEnded: function (sessionEndedRequest, session) {
    }
};

/**
 * Subclasses should override the intentHandlers with the functions to handle specific intents.
 */
AlexaSkill.prototype.intentHandlers = {};

AlexaSkill.prototype.execute = function (event, context) {
    try {
        console.log("session applicationId: " + event.session.application.applicationId);

        // Validate that this request originated from authorized source.
        if (this._appId && event.session.application.applicationId !== this._appId) {
            console.log("The applicationIds don't match : " + event.session.application.applicationId + " and "
                + this._appId);
            throw "Invalid applicationId";
        }

        if (!event.session.attributes) {
            event.session.attributes = {};
        }

        if (event.session.new) {
            this.eventHandlers.onSessionStarted(event.request, event.session);
        }

        // Route the request to the proper handler which may have been overriden.
        var requestHandler = this.requestHandlers[event.request.type];
        requestHandler.call(this, event, context, new Response(context, event.session));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Unexpected exception " + e);
        context.fail(e);
    }
};

var Response = function (context, session) {
    this._context = context;
    this._session = session;
};

function createSpeechObject(optionsParam) {
    if (optionsParam && optionsParam.type === 'SSML') {
        return {
            type: optionsParam.type,
            ssml: optionsParam.speech
        };
    } else {
        return {
            type: optionsParam.type || 'PlainText',
            text: optionsParam.speech || optionsParam
        }
    }
}

Response.prototype = (function () {
    var buildSpeechletResponse = function (options) {
        var alexaResponse = {
            outputSpeech: createSpeechObject(options.output),
            shouldEndSession: options.shouldEndSession
        };
        if (options.reprompt) {
            alexaResponse.reprompt = {
                outputSpeech: createSpeechObject(options.reprompt)
            };
        }
        if (options.cardTitle && options.cardContent) {
            alexaResponse.card = {
                type: "Simple",
                title: options.cardTitle,
                content: options.cardContent
            };
        }
        var returnResult = {
                version: '1.0',
                response: alexaResponse
        };
        if (options.session && options.session.attributes) {
            returnResult.sessionAttributes = options.session.attributes;
        }
        return returnResult;
    };

    return {
        tell: function (speechOutput) {
            this._context.succeed(buildSpeechletResponse({
                session: this._session,
                output: speechOutput,
                shouldEndSession: true
            }));
        },
        tellWithCard: function (speechOutput, cardTitle, cardContent) {
            this._context.succeed(buildSpeechletResponse({
                session: this._session,
                output: speechOutput,
                cardTitle: cardTitle,
                cardContent: cardContent,
                shouldEndSession: true
            }));
        },
        ask: function (speechOutput, repromptSpeech) {
            this._context.succeed(buildSpeechletResponse({
                session: this._session,
                output: speechOutput,
                reprompt: repromptSpeech,
                shouldEndSession: false
            }));
        },
        askWithCard: function (speechOutput, repromptSpeech, cardTitle, cardContent) {
            this._context.succeed(buildSpeechletResponse({
                session: this._session,
                output: speechOutput,
                reprompt: repromptSpeech,
                cardTitle: cardTitle,
                cardContent: cardContent,
                shouldEndSession: false
            }));
        },
        justUseThisJsonPlease: function(json) {
            this._context.succeed(json);
        }
    };
})();
//////
var https = require('https');
var Fact = function () {
    AlexaSkill.call(this, APP_ID);
};

// Extend AlexaSkill
Fact.prototype = Object.create(AlexaSkill.prototype);
Fact.prototype.constructor = Fact;

Fact.prototype.eventHandlers.onSessionStarted = function (sessionStartedRequest, session) {
    console.log("onSessionStarted requestId: " + sessionStartedRequest.requestId + ", sessionId: " + session.sessionId);
    // any initialization logic goes here
};

Fact.prototype.eventHandlers.onLaunch = function (launchRequest, session, response) {
    console.log("onLaunch requestId: " + launchRequest.requestId + ", sessionId: " + session.sessionId);
    //handleEnseFeed(response)
};

/**
 * Overridden to show that a subclass can override this function to teardown session state.
 */
Fact.prototype.eventHandlers.onSessionEnded = function (sessionEndedRequest, session) {
    //console.log("onSessionEnded requestId: " + sessionEndedRequest.requestId + ", sessionId: " + session.sessionId);
    // any cleanup logic goes here
};

Fact.prototype.intentHandlers = {
    "PlayAudio": function (event, context, response) {
        //response.tell('ense is lit')
      //handleEnseFeed(response)
          fetchEnseParse("/latest", function(body) {
            if(body == "error") {
            } 
            else {
                var directives = body.enses.map(function(ense) {
                    var a = ense[1].fileUrl;
                    return {
                         'playBehavior': 'REPLACE_ALL', 
                         'audioItem': 
                             {
                                 'stream': 
                                     {
                                         'url': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.ense.nyc/enses/2017_01_13T16_57_20.190Z/30312/0', 
                                         'token': '33529', 
                                         'offsetInMilliseconds': 0
                                     }
                             }, 
                             'type': 'AudioPlayer.Play'
                    };
                })
            }
            var jsonresponse = {
                'outputSpeech': {
                     'text': '', 
                     'type': 'PlainText'
                    }, 
                'directives': [directives[0]]
            };     
            response.justUseThisJsonPlease( { response: jsonresponse } );
            //queueNext();
        });
    },
    "AudioPlayer.PlaybackNearlyFinished" : function(event, context, response) {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(intent));
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(session));
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        //   console.log("dog")
        //   var stream = {
        //     "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.ense.nyc/enses/violetindigoviolet/30034/0",
        //     "token": "some_token",
        //     "expectedPreviousToken": "33529",
        //     "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
        //   };
        //   response.audioPlayerPlayStream("ENQUEUE", stream);
        //   response.justUseThisJsonPlease( { response: stream } );
            var second = 
            {
              "type": "AudioPlayer.Play",
              "playBehavior": "REPLACE_ENQUEUED",
              "audioItem": {
                "stream": {
                  "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.ense.nyc/enses/violetindigoviolet/30034/0",
                  "token": "33530",
                //   "expectedPreviousToken": "33529",
                  "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
                }
              }
            }
            response.justUseThisJsonPlease( { response: second } );
    },
        "AudioPlayer.PlaybackFinished" : function(event, context, response) {
            var speechOutput = "Goodbye"; 
            response.tell(speechOutput); 
    },
    "AMAZON.HelpIntent": function (intent, session, response) {
        response.ask("You can say play ense feed or, you can say exit... What can I help you with?", "What can I help you with?");
    },
    "AMAZON.StopIntent": function (intent, session, response) {
        var speechOutput = "Goodbye";
        response.tell(speechOutput);
    },
    "AMAZON.CancelIntent": function (intent, session, response) {
        var speechOutput = "Goodbye";
        response.tell(speechOutput);
    }
};



function queueNext(event, second) {
      console.log ('trains')
        var response = {

        'outputSpeech': 
        {
         'text': '', 
         'type': 'PlainText'
        }, 
             'directives': 
             [
                 {
                     'playBehavior': 'REPLACE_ALL', 
                     'audioItem': 
                 {
                     'stream': 
                     {
                         'url': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.ense.nyc/enses/violetindigoviolet/30034/0', 
                         'token': '33529', 
                         'offsetInMilliseconds': 10000
                     }
                 }, 
                 'type': 'AudioPlayer.Play'}

             ] 
        }; 
    //   second.succeed( { response: response } );
}

function handleEnseFeed(response) {
  https.get('https://api.ense.nyc/latest', function (res) {
      var body = '';

      if (res.statusCode != 200)

      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
          body += chunk;
      });

      res.on('end', function (par1, par2) {
          body = JSON.parse(body);
          var enses = body.enses;

          response._context.succeed(thisResponse);

      }).on('error', function (e) {

      });

  });
}


function fetchEnseParse(url, handler) {
    const getEnseOptions = {
            host : "api.ense.nyc",
            path : url
        };
    const req = https.request(getEnseOptions, (res) => {
            var body = '';
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', (chunk) => body += chunk);
            res.on('end', () => {
                // If we know it's JSON, parse it
                if (res.headers['content-type'] && res.headers['content-type'].indexOf('application/json') != -1) {
                    body = JSON.parse(body);
                    handler(body);
                } else {
                    handler("error");
                }

            });
        });

        req.on('error', function() {
            handler("error");
        });
        req.end();
};


// Create the handler that responds to the Alexa Request.
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    // Create an instance of the SpaceGeek skill.
    var fact = new Fact();
    console.log("tractor")
    // queueNext(); 
    // var api = testFuntion();
    fact.execute(event, context);
};
```